# Why identical spheres gain identical charges?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

My textbook quotes

> Because the spheres are identical, connecting them means that they end up with identical charges.

One sphere is neutral and another has charge $+Q$ initially. After connecting them with very thin conducting wire they both acquire same amount of charge $+Q/2$.

Can anyone explain the mechanism of charge transfer please? And also why above quoted implication is true?

Comment: Given that the charges can freely move from one sphere to the other, and that the spheres are indistinguishable, can you propose any mechanism as to why one sphere ends up with more charge than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to realize is that the spheres must have equal charge *density* on their surfaces (and it will be concentrated on their surfaces, assuming that they are conductors - your book probably discusses this point). The reason is that if one sphere acquired more positive charge density than the other, it would have higher electrostatic potential (if you haven't gotten to this idea yet, it basically means that it would be energetically favorable for negative charges to migrate towards the sphere and positive charges to migrate away from it). In other words, any charge density imbalance between the two spheres will cause a migration of electrons in a way that cancels the imbalance - so when the two bodies reach equilibrium, their charge densities will be identical as desired.

Now, because the spheres are identical, they also have equal surface area - and equal charge density distributed across equal surface area will ultimately mean equal total charge as desired. If one sphere was bigger than the other, the charge would be distributed proportional to their two surface areas.

Answer (score 2):

Charges in a conducting material are free to move, hence a conducting volume is an equipotential volume, as the presence of any potential difference (electric field) will make charges move until there is no potential difference. Now, when two identical spheres are connected by a metallic conductor, both spheres come to the same potential. Now for both spheres to have the same potential, they must have equal charges as both are identical.
Initially, the positively charged sphere has positive charges trying to move away from each other due to mutual repulsion. When this is connected to the uncharged sphere, these charges get a path and space to move, so they move until the repulsion from both sides is equal to the charges in the conductor, i.e, both are at the same charge level.

Answer (score 0):

Initially there is a potential difference between the two spheres.
Charge flows between them until the spheres are at the same potential which, if the spheres are identical and remembering that the potential of a sphere is proportional to the charge on it, means each sphere has half the charge.

It is no different to the same result when two capacitors with the same capacitance exchange charge.  In the case of the spheres the other “plate” is the ground.